# c# copy all the children of canvas to another canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas

I am trying to find a way to copy all the children of one canvas to another canvas. Type doesn't matter because it has different types of children.

```
 private void add_template_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       root.Children.Clear();
       foreach(var c in Template_canvas1.Children)
       {
           root.Children.Add(c);
       }
   }
```

Above code gives an error "Invalid operation error".
I want to copy children from template_canvas1 to root canvas. Suggestions?

Comment: What is not working about your current code?

Comment: It says invalid operation error

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is, that a `UIElement` can only belong to one parent at a time. In order to add your items into the `root` canvas, you need to first remove them from the `Template_canvas1` canvas.

See the following code. I create an array of the `UIElements` to copy, and then remove them from `Template_canvas1` before adding them to `root`.

```
private void add_template_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var childrenList = Template_canvas1.Children.Cast<UIElement>().ToArray();
    root.Children.Clear();
    foreach (var c in childrenList)
    {
        Template_canvas1.Children.Remove(c);
        root.Children.Add(c);
    }
}
```

There is one more option, if you don't want to remove the items from `Template_canvas1`, you can create a Deep Copy of the UIElements. See also the following where I do not remove the items from `Template_canvas1`:

```
private void add_template_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    root.Children.Clear();
    foreach (UIElement child in Template_canvas1.Children)
    {
        var xaml = System.Windows.Markup.XamlWriter.Save(child);
        var deepCopy = System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Parse(xaml) as UIElement;
        root.Children.Add(deepCopy);
    }
}
```

Comment: that's the most simplest and the brilliant answer i have found :)

Comment: @thewarri0r9: I also added another option for you to try.

Comment: Another option doesn't work for the windows phone sdk, can you suggest some changes